# Finding the value of $x$

Tags: geometry

[image]

I'm trying to find the value of $x$. For that, I need to get some help. Let's call $\angle A = 2\beta $, $\angle B = \alpha$ and $\angle C = 60$ We know that

$$\triangle ABC = 180 $$

$$\angle A  +\angle B  +\angle C = 180$$

Hence we have

$$\beta  + \alpha = 60$$

My apologies if I'm wrong. Can you explain how to proceed?

Regards

Comment: Is it safe to assume that all the central angles are right?

Comment: @RhysHughes Yes, feel free! :)

Comment: Then $x$ is $30^\circ$.

Comment: How did you get from $\angle A+\angle B+\angle C=180$ to $\beta+\alpha=60$? I get $2\beta+\alpha=180-60=120$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the shape is a kite and that all central angles are right angles; the solution is pretty straightforward.

If $\triangle ABC$ $= 180^\circ$

Then $\triangle DCB=180^\circ$

Focus on the right triangle $DC$. Since we're assuming that the central angles are right angles, $
x = 180-90-60$

Answer (score 0):

If the angles in the centre are right angles and therefore $90^0$, then angle $CDM$, (where $M$ is the centre) is $180-90-60=30^0$, and since $CDM=x; x=30^0$ too. (The line $AD$ bisects the angle $CDB$)

Comment: What if the central angles aren't right? Is there a way to proceed?

Comment: Take $ABCD$ as a regular four-sided shape. $ABC=DBC=ACB=DCB=60^0$, then $360^0=240^0+4x\to x=30^0$